# Excel: split cell by delimiter and iterate through values

Tags: arrays, excel, iteration, delimiter

I have a cell that might contain a single value

> e.g. "images/dog.jpg"

or might contain multiple values, separated by a comma delimiter

> e.g. "images/dog.jpg,images/cat.jpg,images/pig.jpg"

If it just contains the single element, the formula is pretty straightforward. If it contains multiple values, I should iterate through those values and do something with each value.

Here's an example of what I've got so far (given the cell is B2)

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(",";B2))); "<img src=""" & B2 & """>"; FOREACH(SPLITBYDELIMITER(",";B2); "<img src=""" & B2 & """>"))
```

Where the FOREACH (iteration) and SPLITBYDELIMITER should become correct formulas. I don't know if (and how) this is possible however without using multiple columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend normalizing your data, and storing only one path per cell in your Excel Workbook.  If you have access to VBA, it would be easy to remedy this.  Or, you could change the way you are bringing in your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be going at this the wrong way. By simply altering the comma delimiter into appropriate bolerplate text you should acheive the desired result.

```
="<img src="&CHAR(34)&SUBSTITUTE(A3, ",", CHAR(34)&">,<img src="&CHAR(34))&CHAR(34)&">"
```

[image]

Comment: That might be a good workaround indeed, didn't think of that. Thanks!